# Closure of $M=\left\{\frac{1}{n}\::\:n\in \mathbb{N}\right\}$ in $\Bbb A^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology

> Find the closure of the set $M=\left\{\frac{1}{n}\::\:n\in \mathbb{N}\right\}$ on the line in the Zariski topology.

As I understand it, closed sets in the Zariski topology are all one-point sets, but then the closure of the set $M$ will be the intersection of all closed sets containing the set $M$. That is, the closure of the set $M$ will be the set $M$ itself.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g*., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Comment: @islamm Thanks. I'll take a look at these links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the affine line $\mathbb{A}^1_k=\operatorname{Spec} k[t]$, the closure of the set $M$ will be $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ in the Zariski topology.

Note the closed subsets in $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ are given by $V(\mathfrak a)$ for an ideal $\mathfrak a$ in $k[t]$. $k[t]$ being PID, any such ideal $\mathfrak a$  will be principal. So $\mathfrak a=(f)$ for some polynomial $f\in k[t].$

But since a non-zero $f$ has atmost finitely many roots, $V(f)$ will have atmost finitely many points. Now $M$ being infinite, closure of $M$ will be entire $\mathbb{A}^1_k$.